# Call assignment from another function - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.4

How do i call an assignment that belongs to another function?

Example:

```
def get(event):
    barcode = e.get()

def check():
    ic = get.barcode()
```

I get error like: `'get' is not defined`.
How do i call my barcode in the check()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Return the barcode in `get`:

```
def get(event):
    barcode = event.get()
    return barcode
```

Then in `check`, you can call `get` to obtain the barcode:

```
def check():
    your_event_variable = 'something' # whatever it may be
    barcode = get(your_event_variable)
    ic = barcode.barcode()
```

Comment: what if i took away the (event)?

Comment: Well it's the input to the function. If you don't pass it in, how are you going to get the barcode?